# How to configure additional modules to nginx after installation?

Tags: nginx

I have installed Nginx in our redhat machine using rpm. Now we want to add nginx-rtmp module, but inorder to add new module as per the document i need to build it by downloading the tar ball. Does it mean that i have to remove the rpm and install it as per the document.

Ref: https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki/Getting-started-with-nginx-rtmp

```
./configure --add-module=/usr/build/nginx-rtmp-module
make
make install
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Unlike Apache, all modules, including the 3rd party modules, are going to be compiled into nginx. So every time you want to add a new module, you have to recompile nginx.

So yes, you have to install it as per the document. There is no much value of keeping 2 nginx runtimes on the same server any way. So you may also want to remove the previous nginx.

Comment: Does rpm comes with all the third party modules? For example we are able to configure secure download module with out any compiling or rebuild. Do you think rtmp is included in the nginx rpm?

Comment: Don't think so. Check http://wiki.nginx.org/Modules for the list of modules included in nginx distribution.

Comment: Do I have to register nginx as a service manually after `make install`?
It also does seem like the config is no longer done through sites-available and sites-enabled but in one large config file under `pathtonginx/conf/nginx.conf`.

Comment: Chuan Ma, could you edit your answer like atrioom's question?

Comment: I have installed it using `sudo apt-get install`, what should I do ?

Answer (score 43):

With nginx 1.9.11, it's not necessary to recompile the server, as they added support for dynamic modules. Take a look here:
https://www.nginx.com/blog/dynamic-modules-nginx-1-9-11/

Comment: "In the first release of dynamic modules, you still need to compile the optional NGINX modules at the same time as the NGINX binary" from the source you quoted.

Comment: @Leia sure but if you get nginx from a repository, you can also pull binaries of the optional modules from the same repository, as long as whomever maintains the repository builds them together.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem where the auth-pam module broke after an upgrade. Here's what fixed it for me (debian stretch/sid, nginx 1.10.2):

```
apt install libnginx-mod-http-auth-pam
ln -s /usr/share/nginx/modules-available/mod-http-auth-pam.conf /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-auth-pam.conf
```

The config file contains a single “load_module” directive which tells nginx to dynamically load the module on startup. As [jekennedy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1019384/jekennedy) mentioned, this would only apply to newer versions of nginx that support dynamic module loading.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you have to uninstall nginx (installed via rpm) and re-install it according to the mentioned document that is from source file. There are some disadvantages of installing nginx using source, like you cannot use nginx as a service. [**Here**](https://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2016/05/add-module-to-nginx.html), you can find instructions to do same thing with all the functionalities you get while installing nginx using OS-respective packages.

Answer (score 3):

Following the steps in this post from the nginx blog page called ["Compilation of Dynamic Modules for NGINX Plus"](https://www.nginx.com/blog/compiling-dynamic-modules-nginx-plus/), i could compiled the RTMP módule, downloading the `nginx-rtmp-module` from [Github](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module) and import it on my webserver.

Regards.